# Dynamic avro schema creation

Tags: json, avro

How to create avro schema for below json code

```json
{
    "_id" : "xxxx",
    "name" : "xyz",
    "data" : {
        "abc" : {
            "0001" : "gha",
            "0002" : "bha"
        }
    }
}
```

Here,

```json
  "0001" : "gha",
  "0002" : "bha"
```

`key: value` would be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a schema like this does what you want?

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MySchema",
  "namespace": "my.name.space",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "_id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "data",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Data",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "abc",
            "type": {
              "type": "map",
              "values": "string"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It's not dynamic, but you can add as many key-value pairs to  the map as you like. Field names starting with a numeric value [aren't allowed](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#names) in Avro.